# gurobi basic example how to print the total minimal cost?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using gurobipy to solve a transportation problem in python. Transportation Problem, is a linear programming (LP) problem that identifies an optimal solution for transporting one type of product from sources (i) to destinations (j) at the minimum cost (z). You can read more about it in  [this link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/transportation-problem-capacity-allocation-python-using-gaurav-dubey/)

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import csv
import numpy

m = 2
n = 4


# Define data
supply = [100000, 100000]  # Supply nodes
demand = [40500, 22300, 85200, 47500]  # Demand nodes
cost = [
    [52, 32, 11, 69],
    [45, 84, 76, 15],
]  # Cost of transportation from supply i to demand j


theModel = gp.Model()

# Define decision variables
flow = theModel.addVars(m, n, lb=0, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="flow")


# Define supply constraints
for i in range(m):
    theModel.addConstr(gp.quicksum(flow[i, j] for j in range(n)) <= supply[i], name=f"supply_{i}")


# Define demand constraints
for j in range(n):
    theModel.addConstr(gp.quicksum(flow[i, j] for i in range(m)) >= demand[j], name=f"demand_{j}")
    
    
# Define objective function
theModel.setObjective(gp.quicksum(flow[i, j] * cost[i][j] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)), sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)


theModel.optimize()
# Print results
if theModel.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print(f"Optimal solution found with objective value {theModel.objVal:.2f}")
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if flow[i, j].x > 0:
                print(f"Flow from supply node {i+1} to demand node {j+1}: {flow[i, j].x:.0f}")
else:
    print("No solution found.")
```

Like this I can print the  optimal shipment sizes from sources to destinations, but how do i print the TOTAL minimal cost of the operation ? I know that this is the supply transferred `{flow[i, j].x:.0f}` so basically how can i print the total cost ? Should it add the cost of each transportation unique?

Output from client:

```
Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 4.575800000000e+06, best bound 4.575800000000e+06, gap 0.0000%
Optimal solution found with objective value 4575800.00
Flow from supply node 1 to demand node 2: 14800
Flow from supply node 1 to demand node 3: 85200
Flow from supply node 2 to demand node 1: 40500
Flow from supply node 2 to demand node 2: 7500
Flow from supply node 2 to demand node 4: 47500
```

Comment: Do you want just the objective or just some terms from the objective?

Answer (score 1):

This is your objective function:

```
theModel.setObjective(gp.quicksum(flow[i, j] * cost[i][j] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)), sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

So, the final objective value of the optimal solution is already the value you are looking for (if I understand your question correctly):

```
Optimal solution found with objective value 4575800.00
```